# Python, how to output an array that is being generated from a feed as audio?

Tags: python, audio

I am working with audio data in a jupyter notebook. Every 5-10 seconds or so, a new numpy array is generated. Each array lasts 5-10 seconds at the standard sample rate of 22000.

I am trying to play these arrays continuously. Example:

```
sr=22000 #given
three_songs = np.array([[0,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,],[1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,],[0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,])

import IPython.display as ipd
for song in three_songs:
   ipd.Audio(song,sr,autoplay=True)
```

And the output would hopefully play the three songs continuously.
IPython.display.audio is failing to produce any outputs from within the loop.

I'm thinking that the problem could be jupyter notebook related. Or I could be outputting the array,sample rate using a more barebones method, but what? Any thoughts from the community?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you feel jupyter is a problem, try it out on local. I am unfamiliar with the library, I would go back and check documentation and understand examples related to the methods used here

Comment: This worked locally. Of course, shifting to a new environment has its challenges, this ended up working well once I was set up.

Comment: New problems emerged of course. Each iteration of the loop to play has a significant pause, which ruins the music.